# Is there such thing as 'too much cleanup' when handling thread interrupts?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt-handling

[This great article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) about best practices for handling interrupts mentions the following:

> Sometimes it is necessary to do some amount of cleanup before propagating the exception. In this case, you can catch InterruptedException, perform the cleanup, and then rethrow the exception.

He then goes on to give an example of a method that catches InterruptedException, does a couple lines of cleanup, and then propagates the exception onward.

His small example makes perfect sense, but let's say I have a much longer interruptible method, whose task is not so simple, and it must be performed atomically. In other words, the amount of 'cleanup' it would need to perform when interrupted is substantial. Is this acceptable? If so, could I be cheeky and just catch the interrupt, perform all of the method's normal workflow (pretend it's 'cleanup'), and then propagate the interrupt at the very end?

In other words, I get that it's important to *properly* handle and propagate interrupts; my question is, how important is it to handle interrupts in a *timely* manner, and *what counts as 'timely'?*

Here's the example (real world) scenario where I'm coming from: I have a thread listening to a message queue; handling each message involves multiple HTTP calls and expensive DB operations, and, as currently (unfortunately) designed, these operations must all be performed atomically. Can I define my thread's interrupt-handling behavior to be: 'when interrupted, finish everything you're doing as normal before propagating the interrupt', or is this stretching the definition of 'cleanup' a little too much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any useful notion of "too little" or "too much" cleanup.  Certainly there is no general way to decide that you have done too little or too much.

Specifically ...

> Can I define my thread's interrupt-handling behavior to be: 'when interrupted, finish everything you're doing as normal before propagating the interrupt', or is this stretching the definition of 'cleanup' a little too much?

There's no definite answer to this.  If it makes sense (e.g. this behaviour is required), then it would be correct to do that.  Whether you *call* it "cleanup" or not is irrelevant.

On the other hand, one of the common use-cases of Java interrupts is to signal to some part of the application to stop what ever it is doing because, for example:

- the server is shutting down, or
- the requested action is taking too long, or
- the client that made the request has "gone away", and there is no other reason to complete the request.

In such cases, "finish everything as normal" may be the wrong strategy, especially if that is going to be expensive.  (Or it may be the right strategy; for example, if there is no reliable way to back out of the sequence of actions that need to be done atomically.)

In short ... we can't tell you whether this is the right thing to do.

> In other words, I get that it's important to properly handle and propagate interrupts; my question is, how important is it to handle interrupts in a timely manner, and what counts as 'timely'?

Again.  These are questions that only make sense (and can only be answered) in the context of *your* application.  It depends ...

---

But I don't think that this (cleanup) is restricted to interrupts.  Consider the example in the article:

```
public class PlayerMatcher {
    private PlayerSource players;

    public PlayerMatcher(PlayerSource players) { 
        this.players = players; 
    }

    public void matchPlayers() throws InterruptedException { 
        Player playerOne, playerTwo;
         try {
             while (true) {
                 playerOne = playerTwo = null;
                 // Wait for two players to arrive and start a new game
                 playerOne = players.waitForPlayer(); // could throw IE
                 playerTwo = players.waitForPlayer(); // could throw IE
                 startNewGame(playerOne, playerTwo);
             }
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {  
             // If we got one player and were interrupted, put that player back
             if (playerOne != null)
                 players.addFirst(playerOne);
             // Then propagate the exception
             throw e;
         }
    }
}
```

What happens (for example) if `waitForPlayers` or `startNewGame` could throw some other exception (checked or unchecked)?  In that case, you could end up with lost players ... just like if you had an `InterruptedException`.

My point ... is that if you are concerned about making the code resilient *in general* (or "atomic") then it would be better to use a `finally` block to do the recovery; e.g.

```
         finally {  
             // Make sure that we *always* put the players back
             if (playerOne != null)
                 players.addFirst(playerOne);
             if (playerTwo != null)
                 players.addFirst(playerTwo);
         }
```

And if you need to do atomic operations that also entail changing state outside of the JVM and/or "the application" ... then even `finally` is not enough.  There are some situations where code in a `finally` block won't be executed; e.g. if the JVM crashes or is terminated by `System.exit()`.  (This is @EJP's point ...)

Comment: This seems like the closest 'answer' (even if it's 'there is no answer')... to be honest I had a feeling there wouldn't be a real clear-cut definition to begin with. I was also curious about what kinds of scenarios interrupts commonly occur in, so thanks for those 3 examples you gave.

Answer (score 2):

The approach you describe is sometimes referred to as "entering 'lame duck' mode", wherein you'll finish what you've already started but won't accept or initiate any new work.

It's fine as long as you document it, so that callers know what to expect. Encountering an `InterruptedException` means that some upstream caller wants to terminate the thread's activity, but safety trumps responsiveness. If you believe that these operations must all complete together (to the best of your ability), and stopping the unit of work with only part of it done would violate some requirement, then you are in your right to adhere to those requirements and put them above the *implied* requirement for timely cooperation with an interruption request.

Ideally, you'd cease any further progress with the transaction and attempt to roll back what you've already completed. However, there's subtlety in that design; you could be far enough along that just finishing the transaction would be faster than rolling back your nearly-complete accomplishments.

Again, the key here is documentation. If you document the behavior and find that your callers complain, then you have to push back on the competing requirement for transactional atomicity.

Comment: I like your point about making things clear through documentation.. it seems the general consensus is that there is no real concrete definition of what is 'too much' to do when interrupted. With that in mind I supposed the next best thing is making sure the behavior is documented clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The end of that same article discusses "noncancelable tasks", which finish what they're doing (even if it may take a long time) before responding to the interruption.  It sounds like that's what you have.

You don't necessarily have to abort what you're doing immediately, but you should set a flag to remember that an interrupt was requested, then re-throw the `InterruptedException` later when the atomic work is done.

Comment: Good point, I think my specific example does fall under that category.

Answer (score 0):

No. What if you get interrupted again? If you need a method to be atomic you have much bigger problems than propagating exceptions.